# WPF with Unity Container - looking for a sample code to register and resolve views and view models

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

i am a newbie to WPF with Prism, trying to create a new application using Prism Unity. When the application starts, it should load a LoginView, After the user enters a valid passcode, LoginView should be replaced with next screen.

Having difficulty understanding the Prism Unity. Any help is appreciated greatly . A Complete sample would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful the following **MSDN Prism Guide** chapter which may help you understand how **Prism with Unity** works:

- [3: Managing Dependencies Between Components Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

In addition, you can find several ***QuickStart*** samples that describe the implementation of **Navigation** feature or **MVVM** pattern for example:

- [View-Switching Navigation QuickStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430881%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)
- [MVVM QuickStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430857%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)
- [UI Composition QuickStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921174%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

Based on your scenario, a possible solution would be to define a **ContentControl** ***Region*** in the **Shell View**, registering the every View in the ***Region*** and *Activating* the **LoginView**. Then, you would be able to *Navigate* through every View that is registered in that ***Region***.

I hope this helped you,

Regard.